# TMUX: /home/kwa/.tmux.conf:1: unknown command: activity-action

Tags: linux, bash, plugins, tmux

I decided to install tmux plugins on my opensuse following the tutorial https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm.

Initially I didn't have a ~/.tmux.conf file, so I created one manually via tmux show -g > ~/.tmux.conf, added the lines for plugins to it and decided to restart.
I got the following error:

```
/home/kwa/.tmux.conf:1: unknown command: activity-action
```

I thought it was because of running sessions in `ps aux | grep -w [t]mux` and decided to turn them off with `kill -USR1 29750`. Didn't work. I killed the server completely with `tmux kill-server` - didn't work. And not all sessions are killed.

Please tell me what to do, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` command shows the list of options. You cannot use list of raw option names and values as `.tmux.conf`. Prepend each line with `set-option`, for example:

```
set-option -g activity-action other
```

If you haven't been using `.tmux.conf` to start with, create a new empty `.tmux.conf` and put there the lines from the tutorial:

```
# List of plugins
# ...

run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```